# Convert column of timestamp integer to Datetime that stop after the hour in a spark Dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I have a spark dataframe like that

[image]

I have timestamp as integer and I want to create another column with the entire date + the hour
I don't understand why this code doesn't work :

```
df = df.withColumn("Date_per_hour", df.cast('date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the Date column to timestamp with the required format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp   

df = df.withColumn("new_date", to_timestamp("Date", "yyyyMMdd"))
```

Note* you asked for the hour also but I don't see that you have in your Date column hour information.
If you have just add it to the format
,for example:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_date", to_timestamp("Date", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss"))
```